# One Singleton for each (generic) type

Tags: java, singleton

I don't know Java very well, so would like to ask if this implementation is OK.
(Thread-safety doesn't matter). I want a single unique singleton for every T class possible.

```
public class MockDatabase<T> {
    private MockDatabase() {}

    private static Map<String, MockDatabase> singletonHolder = new HashMap<String, MockDatabase>();

    public static <T> MockDatabase<T> getInstance(Class<T> clazz) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        MockDatabase<T> singleton = (MockDatabase<T>)singletonHolder.get(clazz.getName());
        if (singleton == null) {
            singleton = new MockDatabase<T>();
            singletonHolder.put(clazz.getName(), singleton);
        }

        return singleton;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you key on `clazz.getName()`, rather than `clazz`?

Comment: You should not be using raw types (`Map<String,MockDatabase>` uses a raw `MockDatabase`). Also, you shouldn't be using the same type letter for the class parameter `T` and the method generic parameter `<T>` as this creates an illusion that they are the same type.

Comment: why don't you  put in cache the singleton instance that you create when the holder has not it  ?

Comment: That's stupid of me @davidxxx, I meant to put it :)

Comment: Shouldn't getInstance() be synchronized: public static synchronized <T> MockDatabase<T> getInstance()...

Comment: What is the aim of `<T>` in the class declaration ? It is not actually used. The class is designed to be  inherited ?

Comment: @davidxxx There are other methods that return the type T, like public T get(Long id), or public void put(Long id, T toAdd)

Comment: Perfect in this case. Nevertheless the <T> declared by the method can shadow the <T> declared by the class. You should use different letters to avoid misleading code. Otherwise it seems ok for a mono-thread access.

Comment: I think you just reinvented the [Multiton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiton_pattern).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Yes, never heard of it before, but good to learn +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution which is also thread safe is to use ClassValue

```
public class MockDatabase<T> {
    private static final ClassValue<MockDatabase> cache = new ClassValue<>() {
         protected MockDatabase computerValue(Class<?> clazz) {
             return new MockDatabase();
         }
    }
    public static <T> MockDatabase<T> getInstance(Class<T> clazz) {
        return (MockDatabase<T>) cache.get(clazz);
    }
}
```

ClassValue will return the same value object for any class and is thread safe.

Note: ClassValue cleans itself up when a Class is no longer referenced.

Comment: That looks much cleaner!

Comment: @EralpB few Java developers know about this class even though it's in java.lang

Answer (score 1):

```
if (singleton == null) {
        singleton = new MockDatabase<T>();
 }
```

Change above code to

```
if (singleton == null) {
       singleton = new MockDatabase<T>();
       singletonHolder.put(clazz.getName(),singleton ); 
}
```

Other wise you will get new object every time